# how to retrieve word by word from richtextbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I am trying to create a programming editor using a rich text box in vb.net. It should change
 the color of text according to that text. For example, the keywords should be displayed in red, and numbers in blue. I can't find how to retrieve word by word from a rich text box  .

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to find the words, and another one for numbers.
Try this website that well help you create your desired regular expressions http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would just take the rich textbox text field and do a string split by space.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to roll-your-own, the editors from SharpDevelop are easily extendable.

SharpDevelop3 uses [SharpTextEditor](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Syntax-highlighting)(WinForms).
SharpDevelop4 uses [AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit) (WPF)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
Dim txt as String = RichTextBox1.Text
Dim arr as String() = txt.Split(" "c) REM split along the whitespace character
For Each i In arr
    If IsNumeric(i) Then 
        REM change the color of the number to blue
Next i
```